# Drop Down list with Image for every Item

Tags: css, asp.net

I am trying to make a Language Selector
and I use this code for drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" Width="200px">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Select Language"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="English" ></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Albanian" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

But, now I want to put Country icons in those 2. I have 2 images in Images folder inside my project. for example Images/EnglishFlag.png
How can I put those into the drop down list?

I saw many videos or code which did that, but they got images from a SQL db.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

Default.aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
 </div>
</form>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable objdt = new DataTable();
            objdt = GetData();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = objdt;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Country";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

            string imageURL = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                switch (DropDownList1.Items[i].Text)
                {
                    case "Bangladesh": imageURL = "Images/flag-of-Bangladesh.png";
                        break;
                    case "China": imageURL = "Images/flag-of-China.png";
                        break;
                    case "Germany": imageURL = "Images/flag-of-Germany.png";
                        break;
                    case "USA": imageURL = "Images/flag-of-USA.png";
                        break;
                }
                ListItem item = DropDownList1.Items[i];
                item.Attributes["style"] = "background: url(" + imageURL + ");background-repeat:no-repeat;";
            }
        }
    }

    public DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable _objdt = new DataTable();

        _objdt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
        _objdt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(long));

        _objdt.Columns.Add("LabelValue");
        var _objrow = _objdt.NewRow();
        _objrow["Country"] = "Bangladesh";
        _objrow["Id"] = 1;

        _objdt.Rows.Add(_objrow);
        _objrow = _objdt.NewRow();
        _objrow["Country"] = "China";
        _objrow["Id"] = 2;
        _objdt.Rows.Add(_objrow);

        _objrow = _objdt.NewRow();
        _objrow["Country"] = "Germany";
        _objrow["Id"] = 3;
        _objdt.Rows.Add(_objrow);

        _objrow = _objdt.NewRow();
        _objrow["Country"] = "USA";
        _objrow["Id"] = 4;
        _objdt.Rows.Add(_objrow);

        return _objdt;
    }
```

Check this - [Bind Images To ASP.NET DropDownList](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/33b051/binding-image-indropdownlist-in-asp-dotnet/)

Comment: Thanks, it gave me something to focus on, but I just wanted a simple drop down list controled in the aspx page. just a simple drop down list.
I mean, the pics to be there before the page loads, not just after it

Comment: You can't bind image directly to ASP.NET DropDownList. You have to do it in the back-end or using jQuery. See my updated post with a link.